# Individual mongoose schema for each user

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I am new to nodejs.
I have a application with mongoose and user login.
Some of the collections in mongoDB are for all users and some like e.g. the customer-collection is individual so that all users have a collection of their own customers.
When the user login and get his jwt-token the individual mongoose models will be instantiated:

```
var models = require('../models')(userID);
```

in the folder /models there is a index.js:

```
var Customer = require('./customermodel'); 

module.exports = function (userID) {
   Customer(userID) 
}
```

the file /models/customermodel.js:

```
var mongooseCustomer = function(userID) {
    var schema = mongoose.Schema({
          _id: { type: Number},
          Name:  { type: String },
          Address:  { type: String },
        }, {collection: userID + 'userID'})
        return mongoose.model(userID + 'customer', schema);
}
Module.exports = mongooseCustomer;
```

The problem occurs when a customer logges in from two different browsers and return the error: 
Cannot overwrite `123customer` model once compiled.
I solved the problem it with changing :

```
var models = require('../models')(userID);
```

to:

```
try {
     var models = require('../models')(userID);
     console.log('Schema was created');
}
catch (err) {
     console.log('User is already logged in');
}
```

Now my question is if the whole setup is too complicated and could there be a more clean way to deal with creating models in a dynamic way?

Comment: What's the rationale behind creating separate collections for each user? It would be similar to creating a new table for each user if you'd be using a SQL database, which doesn't sound like a great idea.

Comment: I am used to work with .net and mySql, and I used to have all the customer rows in one table, but sometimes the queries get complicated with joins of tables, and my great fear was always that an error in a query in particular cases could show the wrong customer to a user. Therefor I was playing with the idea to make separate collections. Anyway with mongoDB there will not be joins like in mySQL and the queries will hopefully not be too long and complicated.

Comment: The setup that @saintedlama proposes in their answer is one that I'm familiar with myself, and which works very well. If you set up your queries properly, and preferably have a QA person to test your system, it's perfectly okay to have data belonging to different users in the same collection.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you really want to stick with dynamically creating collections for users a better way than `try{ } catch(err)` is to query mongoose if there is already a model compiled for the user. The `mongoose.model` function can be used to define **and** retrieve a model:

```
var mongooseCustomer = function(userID) {
  var model = mongoose.model(userID + 'customer');

  if (!model) {
    var schema = mongoose.Schema({
      _id: { type: Number},
      Name:  { type: String },
      Address:  { type: String },
    }, {collection: userID + 'userID'});

    model = mongoose.model(userID + 'customer', schema);
  }

  return model;
};

Module.exports = mongooseCustomer;
```

I expect that your approach of dynamically creating collections for every user will not scale since mongoose is not built for handling 1000th of models and Mongodb has max collection limit as most databases have.

IMHO a better approach could be to use a discriminator in the collections to identify the tenant and expose a db layer to handle tenants in a transparent way.

Let's define a models node.js module that exposes the minimal data layer

```
// First define the schema and model
var customerSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    _id: { type: Number},
    // Additional tenant discriminator
    userID: { type: Number, required: true }, 
    Name:  { type: String },
    Address:  { type: String },
  });

var customerModel = mongoose.model('customer', schema);

module.exports = function(userID) {
  return {
    customer: {
      find: function(query, callback) {
        query.userID = userID;
        customerModel.find(query, callback);
      },

      findOne: function(callback) {
        var query = { userID : userID };
        customerModel.findOne(query, callback);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When using this minimal layer you made sure that the userID is always added to Mongodb functions.

```
var models = require('../models')(123124432);

models.customer.findOne(...);
```

You could also use a mongoose middleware (http://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html) that handles multi tenancy in a transparent way instead of defining your own data layer on top of mongoose.

Comment: This answer is very usefull. With the minimal data layer I can be sure that the userID always is included in the query. So I can move all the customers to the same collection and simply create a schema for the customer collection without adding the userID.
I will also take a deep look into the mongoose middleware link.
Thank you very much for this quick solution :)

Comment: saintedlama I have followed your advise and used mongoose middleware to make sure that the userID is included in all the request to the custom collection. It is really a great tool:

schema.pre('find', function() {
     this.find({'userId':userId});
 });

Comment: I have worked with this some days now. In the first moment it seems that it works fine, but when the model is set, it can not change anymore. That means that the next user that is logged in sees the customers from the first user, because it uses the user id from the user that was logged in first.